# Understanding a voltage multiplier circuit

Tags: voltage

I have a question about this circuit.
I don't really know what it does.
I have searched it up on google and I found something with voltage multiplier.
I don't know what it does or if it is even a voltage multiplier.
Can someone explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I've edited your question title as "Question about a circuit" would apply to 90% of the questions on the site and doesn't explain at all what you are asking about. Also putting "question" in the title of a question is redundant.

Comment: I hope you recognize that this circuit **requires AC input** and delivers DC as output. It will not "voltage-double" if the input is 5V DC.

Comment: Read all about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler

Answer (score 4):

It's called "voltage doubler".

During the positive half cycle D1 conducts and charges C1 to peak value of the input voltage minus one diode drop. Likewise, during the negative half cycle D2 conducts and C2 gets charged to peak value of the input voltage minus one diode drop. Since C1 and C2 are connected in series, the output voltage will be the sum of the voltages across both capacitors: Vo=2 (V<sub>in-pk</sub> - Vf) = 2 × (1.414 × 5 - 0.6) = 12.9V. Depending on the load current, the output voltage may drop due to the output ripple.

Answer (score 1):

It's a voltage doubler.

When the 5 Vrms (7 V peak) is one way round, D1 will charge C1 to 7 V less a diode drop.

When the input is the other way round, D2 will charge C2 to 7 V less a diode drop.

As C1 and C2 are in series, that will deliver their sum, or a little less due to droop, to the load.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is a voltage doubler which is designed by cascading a positive and a negative clamper circuits. It is a specific extension of voltage multiplier. It simply doubles the magnitude of the input AC voltage (in this case 5sinwt).
Note: Here I am not considering the RMS value, only the peak value has been taken into account.
For positive half cycle of the input AC signal, diode 1 will conduct which will result the capacitor (C1) to charge upto 5 - voltage drop across diode. For silicon diode, the voltage drop is 0.7. Therefore, C1 charges to 5-0.7=4.3 volts for positive half of input signal.

Similarly, for negative half, diode 2 conducts and C2 charges to -4.3 volts.

In steady state, both the diodes become off and capacitors retain their charges. Therefore  Vo = 2*4.3= 8.6V